# androidManifest and intent-filter to order activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have 3 Activity in my androidManifest,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="zepod.whatelsecomics" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Activity1"
        android:label="@string/list1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/list2">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity3"
        android:label="@string/addItemToList2">
    </activity>
</application>
```

The first one call the second one 
The second one call the third one
The first one activity is the main activity.

The result of the third one activity is an updated list in the second one (just a form).

But now, if i clik the back button i came back at the third one
How can i force the app to came back at the first activity?
I suppose this depend by androidManifest but i don't understand the intent-filters order

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting to the third activity, call `finish()` to remove the second activity from the stack. That's the easiest way.

There are other ways. This question has been asked a million times on SO, search for it and you'll find alternatives.